# My mac has been hacked, I get a voice notification every second

Tags: macos, ssh

My friend who knew my laptop's password has run some script using ssh remote login. Even though I have removed the authorized_keys file. I am still getting this irritating voice notification. He is running a cron job.
Please Help!

Comment: any idea what this script might be?

Comment: its a cron job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, based on what information I have:

Your friend set up a cronjob. Ok, Let's see what cronjobs there are. run `crontab -l` from terminal

- If there is only one entry in crontab, run `crontab -r`, problem solved.
- If there are multiple entries, you want to run `crontab -e` and remove the offending line.
- If there are no lines, run those commands again with `sudo`
- After removing the cronjob, smack said friend with any object nearby (just don't kill him)
- Change MacBooks Password, and NEVER give ANYONE SSH access again

Comment: You forgot a step.  Smack said friend with a big foam bat for being a idiot and change the laptop's password.

Comment: @Ramhound, how do you manage to end up on all of my answers?

Comment: @Ramhound likes to be engaged in all of the action.

Comment: oh, is that so...

Comment: how do you PM people on SU? anyway @Ramhound, if you want something to do, jump on Insomnia247 and come chat

Comment: You don't.  All we have is the capability to direct a comment to somebody with the `@username` I don't have that capability to jump on Insomnia247 the firewall is extreme where I work Superuser barely works.

Comment: @TD.512 Also can I kill cron process? Everytime I kill that process it re spawns.

Comment: did you do `crontab -e` or `crontab -r`?